# Get $_FILES['tmp_name'] to JSON data and resent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, security

I tried to use AJAX to upload multiple images and sorting data like below data structure.

My question is I use AJAX to get `$_FILES['tmp_name']` add into client side json data, 
(the `$_FILES['tmp_name']` is after choose file upload input, store file to temp location)
Is it any security problem should I notice?

The PHP store function only get the data and move the `$_FILES['tmp_name']` to other position without any validate. but the `tmp_name` path is from client side is it too dangerous and shouldn't do it?

Data structure

```
post_array = {
  "gallery": [
      0: ['file input val', 'file sequence', 'file type', 'tmp_name'],
      1: ['file input val', 'file sequence', 'file type', 'tmp_name'],
       ...
   ]
};
```

Javascript:

```
var form_data = new FormData(),
    post_array = {},
    files = [];

for (var i = 0; i < $('.file-list').length; i++) {

  // ... ajax get $_FILES['tmp_name'], tmp_name = $_FILES['tmp_name']

    var file = [];
    file.push($('.file-list').eq(i).find('.browseimage')[0].files[0]);
    file.push(tmp_name);
    file.push($('.file-list').eq(i).find('.file-sequence input').val());
    file.push($('.file-list').eq(i).find('.file-type input').val());

    files.push(file);
}

post_array['gallery'] = files;

var json_array = JSON.stringify(post_array);

form_data.append('post_array', json_array);

// ... ajax post form_data  store
```

PHP store

```
$post_array = json_decode($_POST['post_array'], true);
// ...
for ($i=0; $i < count($gallery); $i++) { 
    $tmp_name = $gallery[$i][0]['name'];
    $tmp_size = $gallery[$i][0]['size'];
    $tmp_format = $gallery[$i][0]['type'];
    $tmp_location = $gallery[$i][0]['tmp_name'];
    ...

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $file_correct_location);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely read some Info's about this, as there are several security considerations that you have to be aware of.

To answer your question:
No you shouldn't do it that way, as there is a high risk that the path given by the user leads to a folder one level up in the directory structure. Furthermore the file could be a virus or a script that gets executed on the server.

A good starting point for security considerations:
http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/fileupload-security.htm